# grouping toolwindows in menu

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am creating several tool windows and i would like to group them all under the same designated menu or at least a **submenu** of `view`

I am able to make the tool windows using this sort of syntax in the plugin xml:

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
        <toolWindow id="My Sample Tool Window" secondary="true" icon="/myToolWindow/plus.png" anchor="right" factoryClass="myToolWindow.MyToolWindowFactory"/>
</extensions>
```

and I am able to make menus and menu items like this:

```
<actions>
        <group id="SampleMenu" text="Sample Menu" description="Sample menu">
            <action id="Textboxes" class="TextBoxes" text="Text _Boxes" description="A test menu item" />
            <add-to-group group-id="MainMenu" relative-to-action="HelpMenu" anchor="before"  />
        </group>
</actions>
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to combine the two or find the relevant parts in the documentation

Comment: You can't control how toolwindows are presented under View | Tool Windows. You can define your own actions to show your toolwindows, and add those actions in any other place of the menu, as a group or in any way that you prefer.

Comment: @yole that is unfortunate. if you write that as an answer i will accept it. i would also appreciate it if you tell me how to call a toolwindow from an action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control how toolwindows are presented under View | Tool Windows. You can define your own actions to show your toolwindows, and add those actions in any 
other place of the menu, as a group or in any way that you prefer.

To activate a toolwindow programmatically, use:

```
ToolWindowManager.getInstance(project).getToolWindow(YOUR_ID).activate(null);
```